# ismember not working for NaN

Tags: matlab, nan

If I do

```
ismember([NaN 0 3 2],[0 NaN])
```

then the output is

```
0     1     0     0
```

where I obviously expected

```
1     1     0     0
```

I tried

```
ismember(['3' 0 3 2],[0 '3'])
```

then the output is

```
1     1     0     0
```

How can I make ismember work for NaN?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following with the convention that [`NaN ~= NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html#moreabout), `ismember` [treats NaN values as distinct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#btjtp_r-5).  A quick shim that works for your given use case would be:

```
>> ismembernan = @(a,b) ismember(a,b) | (isnan(a) & any(isnan(b)));
>> a = [NaN 0 3 2];
>> b = [0 NaN];
>> ismembernan(a,b)
ans =
     1     1     0     0
```

Comment: ismember has a second return value. How can I get that from ismembernan?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit of a clumsy, but working, approach to go around the `NaN ~= NaN` convention default in MatLab by replacing all the `nan`s by a unique value `val`, do you `ismember` thing and then set to `nan`s all the initially disturbed cells. That way one can use the full functionality of the `ismember` function including second deliverable and the optional `rows` argument.

```
a = [1 NaN 3];
b = [0  0  0;...
     1 NaN 3;...
     0  0  0];
val = rand;
while any([a(:)==val; b(:)==val])
      val = rand;
end
a(isnan(a)) = val;
b(isnan(b)) = val;

[~, ind] = ismember( a, b, 'rows' );
a(a == val) = nan;
b(b == val) = nan;
```